# HtmlWebpackPlugin: wrong hash for script file is injected into html file

Tags: javascript, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I'm trying to use HtmlWebpackPlugin to generate .HTML file

when running build with webpack i get this issue where the src of script tag in HTML file is not same as the script file name

here is my webpack config:

```js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: { index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/index.js') },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.[fullhash].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/'),
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/index.html'),
      minify: true,
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      // HTML
      {
        test: /\.(html)$/,
        use: ['html-loader'],
      },

      // JS
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader'],
      },

      // CSS
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },

      // Images
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|gif|svg)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              outputPath: 'assets/images/',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

this is the generated HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script
      defer="defer"
      src="bundle.3d5baadb547d13677f00.js?3d5baadb547d13677f00"
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script src="1ec740dc7ce75155c1fd.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here is my dist folder:

[image: dist-folder]

as you can see the name of bundle file is okay, but the script tag at the and of the body has wrong src

Comment: i have the same issue. hope someone knows the solution!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution to this in the comments of this Github issue: https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/1638

In the optimization section of your webpack config file, set `realContentHash` to `false`:

```
optimization: {
    // other config ...
    realContentHash: false,
},
```

So for example my webpack configuration object looks like this:

```
{
    mode: ...,
    entry: ...,
    output: ...,
    module: ...,
    plugins: ...,
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [new CssMinimizerPlugin(), "..."],  // other config
        realContentHash: false,
    }
}
```

This can sometimes produce the suboptimal situation where hashes change more than is necessary, but it seems to be the best solution for now (pending updates to the issue.)